# How to suppress the subreport when subreport dataset value has a status of "false"

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, subreport

My scenario is i am working with crystal reports, in that Main report document viewer which consists many sub-reports ,

**Now my problem is**

How to **suppress(Hide) the sub report** based on data set column (database fields) can any one help me to write the expression based on value.

```
1) if database column value is "1" --> Show the sub report.
2) If database column value is "0" --> Hide the sub report.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the formula in Surpress, and enter this formula

```
IF {db_column} = 1 THEN false ELSE true
```